# NoSQL Databases for clients and transaction management

Tags: mysql, mongodb, scalability, database-performance

I pretend to build a intranet portal using nodejs+express+angular, however I would like to know if MongoDB would be a good choice for the database.

- Users have to report their work hours to later submit invoices to clients
- Clients have to be managed (added, edited, deleted)
- I will have to show dashboards with invoice values, top clients and so on. (by performing arithmetic functions)

Would it be easy to relate, for example, the client ID in the hour record with the client itself?

Or should I used a SQL db such as MySQL?

I need facts based on **Performance**, **scalability** etc.

What will happen when my NoSQL DB goes bigger? Will it lose performance?

Comment: Are you talking about millions of rows in your tables?  If not, then "performance" and "scalability" are irrelevant.  If you know SQL, then use a RDBMS; it not, the re-invent that wheel by using a NoSQL.

Comment: Yeah @RickJames eventually it will have millions of rows at a certain stage. I guess I'm going to use rbdms since I'm more comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

*My Experience: I have been using MongoDB & Mysql for the past 2 years 5 months.*

Everything I write here is going to be from ***my personal view and experience.***

These days MongoDB (NoSQL in general) is a buzz word everybody talks about mongoDB, couchDB, MEAN stack etc ... that why we started it and here is what happened:
we found a project that was perfect for mongodb:

1. We had very large user base
2. There was a lot inter dependencies
       between our entity objects i.e Entity A cant live without Entity B
       so we decided to embed the dependent entities.

Still we are using MongoDB for the same project but our database design is very different than our initial database design( which were designed following the mongodb principles):

1. Our app become very slow because sometimes we want to get data
   from more than one collection and mongodb does ot allow us ( now it
   is supported from version >= 3.2). Hence we to do the join on our
   service layer pro grammatically.
2. Loading database entities become very heavy due to the embeded
   documents so we have to move all embeded documents into separate
   collections. Hence our database design is now very flat(i.e looks
   like relational database design).
3. We found a lot orphaned data in our database; initially we
   thought we can implement our data integrity on our repo/service
   layer but it is obvious our implementation was not perfect and
   sometimes we directly run mongo queries on the database console so
   we were actually messing up our data while mongodb kept silent
   laughing at us :)
4. After we finished most of our app's functionality we focused on
   writing reports and doing analysis on our data we found out our
   mongodb queries become very huge and unmanageable; which we believed
   using relational databases like mysql could have eased this.

Bottom line when I started using MongoDB I was very fascinated about it but not afer I know how to use it:

1. It does not complain about data integrity violation. In fact you
   could insert Car instance into Employee collection if you want :D
2. It is very easy to learn specially if you have good javascript
   background; you dont have to learn database languages like SQL. All
   mongo queries are combination of js functions and objects.
3. You can finish an app in matter of weeks or few months; in fact
   we finished our app in 3 months(very complex app).

But now we got a similar project and we choose Mysql instead of Mongodb; we could have replicated the old project and finish it in few weeks but we learned our lesson. If you really care about your app ( ie. your data) go for Mysql(any relational database).

We are only using MongoDB for old projects and [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana)(because it is for logging and we dont care much about our log data)

Who said Mysql does not scale? [Facebook is using 1,800 mysql servers!](http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2008/04/1800-mysql-servers-with-two-dbas/)